# Cordova In App Purchase Consumable Products

Tags: ajax, cordova, in-app-purchase

I want to ask: if I successfully bought a consumable product (example: coins) then I should **add my coins in my database by ajax** with the product that has been bought right?

How can I secure the ajax if I buy it with InApp Purchase?

I mean we can just copy the ajax and execute it with our own code without InApp Purchase right (If we were a hacker that want to get free coins)?

Answer (score 1):

(1) This is **Cordova**. In a production **APP**, there is no easy way for a user to **copy and execute ajax**. Yes, a professional hacker could de-compile you **APP**, and figure out how to get coins for themselves, but would their effort be worth it?

(2) The only **solution** I can recommend is to have your own server which verifies and saves all in-app-purchases, and have your APP synchronize with your server to verify each user's actual **coin balance**.

See https://alexdisler.com/2016/03/20/validating-cordova-in-app-purchases-on-ios-and-android-using-nodejs/ for an example using Cordova and NODEJS.

Personally, my server verifies that every in-app-purchase **reciept** is credited to **one-and-only-one** user. This way, even if the **APP** is **hacked**, they couldn't steal anyone else's **coins**.